# Run custom services on startup with puppet

Tags: linux, debian, puppet

I'm migrating our old process of doing our linux configurations to be managed by puppet but I'm having issues trying to figure out how to do this. We add some custom scripts to the init.d folder on our systems to manage some processes, and then these need this command executed on them to launch on startup:

```
update-rc.d $file defaults
```

So what I'm doing with puppet is that I have all these scripts residing a directory, and I copy them over to init.d. I then want to call 'exec' on each of these files with the former command and use the file name as an argument. This is what I have so far:

```
#copy init files    
file { '/etc/init.d/':
      ensure => 'directory',
      recurse => 'remote',
      source => ["puppet:///files/init_files/"],
      mode => 755,
      notify => Exec[echo],
    }

exec { "echo":
  command => "update-rc.d $file defaults",
  cwd => "/tmp", #directory to execute from
  path => "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:",
  refreshonly => true
}
```

This will copy all the files and it calls exec when something is added/updated, but what I can't figure out is how to pass the name of the file as an argument into the exec command. It seems I'm really close but I just can't find anything to help with what I need to do. Is this the right way to try and achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your probably not going to accomplish that if your using `ensure => 'directory'`. You will want to declare the `file` resource for each individual init script. And the exec isn't the way to go to enable a service. Use the `service` resource.

```
 file { '/etc/init.d':
   ensure => 'directory',
   mode   => '0755'
 }

 file { '/etc/init.d/init_script_1':
   ensure => 'present',
   owner  => 'root',
   group  => 'root',
   mode   => '0755',
   notify => Service['init_script_1']
 }

 file { '/etc/init.d/init_script_2':
   ensure => 'present',
   owner  => 'root',
   group  => 'root',
   mode   => '0755',
   notify => Service['init_script_2']
 }

 service { 'init_script_1':
   ensure => running,
   enable => true
 }

 service { 'init_script_2':
   ensure => running,
   enable => true
 }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, to all points. Additionally, create a defined type that consolidates the `file`/`type` pair. You can then very simply enumerate your files like `my_initscript { [ 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' ]: }`.

Comment: Thanks guys, this is exactly what I was looking for. I had to look at managing my scripts with upstart instead but that's much more effective for what I want.

Comment: @Felix: I set up a defined type to take different files and launch the services, but I'm a bit lost on what you mean by iterating it. I have it set up like

`define foo($file=$title, $source){
   file { '$file':source => $source}}

foo { 'bar':source => 'baz'}`

But how do I call foo using a list of different name/sources?

Comment: @aykyu The `source` should only be a parameter if it is different for each initscript. Hardcode it otherwise. All files with the same source can be declared at once: `foo { [ 'one', 'two', 'three' ]: source => 'baz' }`. If you have more trouble getting that to work, ask that as a new question, please.